# Keras - validation score in fitting log is not correct

Tags: machine-learning, classification, tf.keras

I am training a multitarget classification model with keras. My architecture is:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Input, Dense
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model

imput_ = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1]))
x = Dense(50, activation="relu")(imput_)
x = Dense(n_targets, activation="sigmoid", name="output")(x)
model = Model(imput_, x)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])
```

Then I fit my model like this:

```
model.fit(X_train, y_train.toarray(), validation_data=(X_test, y_test.toarray()), epochs=5)
```

The fitting loss shows this:

```
Epoch 1/5
36/36 [==============================] - 1s 10ms/step - loss: 0.5161 - accuracy: 0.0614 - val_loss: 0.3365 - val_accuracy: 0.1434
Epoch 2/5
36/36 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 0.2761 - accuracy: 0.2930 - val_loss: 0.2429 - val_accuracy: 0.4560
Epoch 3/5
36/36 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2255 - accuracy: 0.4435 - val_loss: 0.2187 - val_accuracy: 0.5130
Epoch 4/5
36/36 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.2037 - accuracy: 0.4800 - val_loss: 0.2040 - val_accuracy: 0.5199
Epoch 5/5
36/36 [==============================] - 0s 5ms/step - loss: 0.1876 - accuracy: 0.4996 - val_loss: 0.1929 - val_accuracy: 0.5250
<keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fe0a549ee10>
```

But then if I run:

```
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
accuracy_score(np.round(model.predict(X_test)), y_test.toarray())
```

I got the following score:

```
0.07772020725388601
```

Shouldn't the score be equal to the val accuracy score in the last epoch?

Answer (score 0):

With that loss and activation function, your top probability might not be higher than 0.5, and it would become 0 when you use `np.round`.

Try:

```
y_pred = np.argmax(model.predict(X_test), axis=1)
```

```
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred)
```

Comment: I don't want to use argmax because there might be more than one positive target per sample (or even zero).
If the problem is the threshold, how can I know which one was used for computting the fitting log score?